# Is there a tool that will automatically generate web controls from user controls? (incl HTML markup)

Tags: c#, user-controls, web-controls

Is there a way to create web controls from user controls which will for instance turn the following markup:

```
<div id="pnlTest">
     <asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server" />
</div>
```

In to:

```
Panel pnlTest = new Panel();
Label lblTest = new Label();
pnlTest.Controls.Add(lblTest);
```

A lot of the examples that I have seen involve hooking the OnRender method and just outputting HTML to an HTMLWriter. Is there a better alternative?

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: Can you please explain the purpose of this as I don't get it...

Comment: We have a bunch of usercontrols that need to be more portable (e.g. compiled in to a single DLL)

Answer (score 0):

I think what your original requirement is to have the user controls portable so that they can be reused with other projects, without Copy pasting the controller code. Check out this method for embedding [Embedding Resources in ASP.NET 2.0 Assemblies](http://aspalliance.com/726), so that you'll be able to share and reuse the user controls.